How to get WordPress with Nginx Proxy Manager
I am getting the following error through Nginx Proxy Manager:

504 Gateway Time-out

My Setup:
PhotonOS Minimal with Docker enabled, and Portainer to manage it
Using Portainer to deploy this stack :
version: '3.8'
services:
  wordpress1:
    image: wordpress:php7.2-apache
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: Site1.co.nz
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: Site1.co.nz
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: Email
    volumes:
  Nginx Proxy Manager    - Site1_data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - wp-network
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
      - "8441:443"

  wordpress2:
    image: wordpress:php7.2-apache
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: Site2.co.nz
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: Site2.co.nz
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: Emailz
    volumes:
      - Site2_data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - wp-network
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
      - "8442:443"

  wordpress3:
    image: wordpress:php7.2-apache
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: Site3.co.nz
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: Site3.co.nz
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: Emails
    volumes:
      - Site3_data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - wp-network
    ports:
      - "8083:80"
      - "8443:443"

  wordpress4:
    image: wordpress:php7.2-apache
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: Site4.co.nz
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: Site4.co.nz
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: Emails
    volumes:
      - Site4_data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - wp-network
    ports:
      - "8084:80"
      - "8444:443"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - wp-network
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - wp-network

  nginx-proxy-manager:
    image: jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "81:81"
    volumes:
      - npm_data:/data
      - npm_letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - wp-network

networks:
  wp-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  Site1_data:
  Site2_data:
  Site3_data:
  Site4_data:
  mysql_data:
  npm_data:
  npm_letsencrypt:

Once deployed I am going through the basic provisioning of a site so I have something to test with, I do this with the IP of the PhotonOS VM and the assigned port for the Wordpress Container, 8081
Add this to wp-config.php of the test site and place it on the volume (Via Portainer Volume View) :
/* Handle SSL and reverse proxy headers */
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https') {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}

/* Allow both HTTP and HTTPS */
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);

These are the steps I to reproduce the problem:

Restart the Wordpress Container
Add the IP of the PhotonOS VM to my hostfile, with site1.co.nz and www.site1.co.nz as DNS entries
Connect on the IP of the PhotonOS VM with :81 to connect to  Nginx Proxy Manager
Complete the forced provisioning of Nignx Proxy Manger
Add a proxy host with site1.co.nz as the DNS entry and the forwarding details as the IP of the Container or the IP of the internal Container for Wordpress1.. I then specify port 8081
Get the error

Troubleshooting:

Various sites Forum posts, this is the most comprehensive. I get suck at step 7 obviously  - https://www.reddit.com/r/nginxproxymanager/comments/10u0wbj/running_wordpress_behind_nginx_proxy_manager/

Tried various Stack builds, and even built a custom container with very basic Plotly site.. Which proxied great!! That is on port 5000

Provisioned  Nginx Proxy Manager on a whole new PhotonOS Vm with docker (Thinking local permissions or something is preventing access) but I note I can access phpmyadmin and mysql no problems


